# looking for a python library to detect post requests inside an url

Tags: python

I'm looking for a library, I don't know if it's exists. I need to parse an url to check if there is a post request form inside it. If there is one, it should list the parameters of that post request. Example process:

-url: http://www.example.com

-It has a post request form to "saveprofile.php" with parameters "name,lastname,password"

-Save those information to a text file

Do you know any library which achieves this goal?

Comment: Ever heard about the standard library? Search for urlparse...

Comment: Check out [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) in the stdlib

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, use [**urllib.parse**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse):

```
import urllib.parse

parse_result = urllib.parse.urlparse("http://www.example.com")
print(parse_result)

# ParseResult(scheme='http',
#             netloc='www.example.com',
#             path='',
#             params='',
#             query='',
#             fragment='')

parse_result = urllib.parse.urlparse("http://www.example.com?name=John&lastname=Doe&password=S3crEt")
print(parse_result)

# ParseResult(scheme='http',
#             netloc='www.example.com',
#             path='',
#             params='',
#             query='name=John&lastname=Doe&password=S3crEt', fragment='')
```

Comment: it seems it's for get requests only?